# "Unexpected Character" on Decoding JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart

The following is the code:

```
    static TodoState fromJson(json) {
          JsonCodec codec = new JsonCodec();
            List<Todo> data = codec.decode(json["todos"]);
            VisibilityFilter filter = codec.decode(json['visibilityFilter']);

     return new TodoState(todos: data,
                          visibilityFilter: filter);
  }
```

Error produced by Android Studio:

> [VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
>       FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 3)

Any idea how to make it work?

[image]

This is the output of the Json as produced by Redux.

Comment: What does your json look like?

Comment: it is auto made by redux; with redux persist, it is basically an array with objects inside, the objects have an id(int), text(string), a completed(bool)

Comment: `codec.decode(json["todos"].replace("\ufeff", ""));` if it were a UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: i dont need to replace it, just pass it to a list to reused, and save . data locally.

Comment: Please post the output of the JSON you get from Redux

Comment: Where is the JSON first interpreted? Have you checked that your JSON input it valid? Is the error from within the block of code that you have posted or does it in fact occur elsewhere?

Comment: The only problem i think is that the output of the Json cant be converted to work with it. Posted the output of the Json in the post

Comment: the value part seems not correct, Please check that

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Json keys (in this case id, text, completed), are strings and thus there should be quotes (') around them. Perhaps you should look at the source of redux why they make a json this way.

Comment: i see why, but nothing changes if i fix that, still that error

Comment: I have a similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635263/decode-a-response-from-a-catch-in-dart   any idea?

Comment: Ensure the string you are receiving is jsonEncoded. For instance if you are storing your todos in a local database as a string encode it using JsonEncode(todos) before storing and while fetching from database decode it using `jsonDecode`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a problem with your code as well as the string you're trying to parse. I'd try to figure out where that string is being generated, or if you're doing it yourself post that code as well.

Valid Json uses "" around names, and "" around strings. Your string uses nothing around names and '' around strings.

If you paste this into DartPad, the first will error out while the second will succeed:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  JsonCodec codec = new JsonCodec();
  try{
    var decoded = codec.decode("[{id:1, text:'fdsf', completed: false},{id:2, text:'qwer', completed: true}]");
    print("Decoded 1: $decoded");
  } catch(e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  }

  try{
    var decoded = codec.decode("""[{"id":1, "text":"fdsf", "completed": false},{"id":2, "text":"qwer", "completed": true}]""");
    print("Decoded 2: $decoded");
  } catch(e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  }
}
```

The issue with your code is that you expect the decoder to decode directly to a List. It will not do this; it will decode to a `dynamic` which happens to be a `List<dynamic>` whose items happen to be `Map<String, dynamic>`.

See [flutter's Json documentation](https://flutter.io/json/) for information on how to handle json in Dart.

Comment: I have a similar problem I think : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635263/decode-a-response-from-a-catch-in-dart  Any idea?

Comment: my json response doesnt have " " . what should i do?

Comment: @masoudmjm well first run your json through a checker like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, that'll at least tell you if it is valid or not. If it is valid then it might be worth opening an issue on the parsing library.

Answer (score 13):

If Anyone came here and your are using `dio` package to call http request you need to set `responseType` to `plain`

```
 BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: "<URL>",
    responseType: ResponseType.plain
  );
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Bawantha... u saved my time.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if that's the case, but I got a similar error when me JSON looks like this

[
  {
   ...
  },
]

and not like this

[
  {
   ...
  }
]

The comma was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also have similar type of error, Be make sure that the argument of .decode method shouldn't be empty object.

```
try {
if(json["todos"].isNotEmpty) {
List<Todo> data = codec.decode(json["todos"]);
}
if(json["todos"].isNotEmpty) {
VisibilityFilter filter = codec.decode(json['visibilityFilter']);
}
}
catch(e) {
print(e);
}
```

Do try this, hope it will work for you.