# Json.decode hangs while parsing JSON in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, decode

The body of my response contains the following data

`[{"AttendanceID":null,"MobilePrefID":"Ab12949","DateTimeInString":"08/01/2019","DateTimeOutString":"08/01/2019","TimeIn":"18:16","TimeOut":"18:18","SignInAddress":null,"SignOutAddress":null}]`

My code to decode to JSON is as follow

```
var dec = json.decode(resp.body)
```

However, the command gets stuck here and does not produce the result.

Comment: Have you got any error? Please put console output

Comment: Nothing, No error is being thrown.

Comment: add more code to identify the issue , how do you fetch the data?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Above JSON decodes easily. Try `flutter clean`

Comment: Same problem, `flutter clean` did not solve the issue. @user3513192 how have you handled it?

Comment: Turns out my error was after the JSON was parsed. Strangely flutter did not warn me about the exception that was being thrown, but using a try-catch block showed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Got reference from

["Unexpected Character" on Decoding JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650168/unexpected-character-on-decoding-json)

And tried your code as

```
 JsonCodec codec = new JsonCodec();
  try{
    String strBody = """[{"AttendanceID":null,"MobilePrefID":"Ab12949","DateTimeInString":"08/01/2019","DateTimeOutString":"08/01/2019","TimeIn":"18:16","TimeOut":"18:18","SignInAddress":null,"SignOutAddress":null}]""";
    print(strBody);
    var decoded = codec.decode(strBody);
    print("Decoded 1: $decoded");
  } catch(e) {
    print("Error: $e");
  }
```

You will be got result

Comment: Not producing error:. One interesting thing When I am printing response.body , output is incomplete . e.g[{"AttendanceID":null,"MobilePrefID":"Ab12949","DateTimeInString":"08/01/2019","DateTimeOutString":"08/01/2019","TimeIn":"18:16","TimeOut":"18:18","SignInAddress":null,"SignOutAddress":null},{"AttendanceID":null,"MobilePrefID":"Ab12949"