# Decode a response from a catch in Dart

Tags: dart

I try to decode the response returned from a catch, here is what I tried :

```
try{
  ...
} catch (err) {
    //JsonCodec codec = new JsonCodec(); // doesn't work
    //var decoded = codec.decode(err);
    ...
 }
```

> Error: type '_Exception' is not a subtype of type 'String'

print(err) :

> Exception: {
>              "error": {
>                  "code": "invalid_expiry_year"
>              }
>           }

I would like to get the value of "code", I tried many things but it doesn't work,

Any idea?

```
 print(err.code);
```

then I get :

[image]

Comment: `err.code` did not work? It does not look like it needs decoding

Comment: @SterlingArcher I updated the question with what I get, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* get the `message` property and `jsonDecode` it.

```
try {
} catch (e) {
  var message = e.message; // not guaranteed to work if the caught exception isn't an _Exception instance
  var decoded = jsonDecode(message);
  print(decoded['error']['code'])'
}
```

All of this strikes as a misuse of `Exception`. Note that you generally *don't* want to `throw Exception(message);`. Putting a json encoded message in there is not the best way to communicate details about the exception. Instead, write a custom implementation of `Exception` and catch the specific type.

```
class InvalidDataException implements Exception {
  final String code;
  InvalidDataException(this.code);
}

try {
} on InvalidDataException catch(e) {
  print(e.code); // guaranteed to work, we know the type of the exception
}
```

See the [docs for `Exception`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Exception-class.html):

> Creating instances of Exception directly with `new Exception("message")` is discouraged, and only included as a temporary measure during development, until the actual exceptions used by a library are done.

See also https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a solution :

```
catch (response) {
    var err=response.toString().replaceAll('Exception: ', '');
   final json=JSON.jsonDecode(err);
   print(json['error']['code']);
}
```