# Lost In Translation: Issue Parsing JSON to Object in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Background: Project uses Yelp API in JSON to sift through business data. Two types of endpoints are use - https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search and https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business. The first part of this projects works as expected where the business_search api is parsed, saved as a list of strings and converted to a Business objects when it is needed to be displayed. The JSON -> Object code is as follows:

```
factory Business.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Business(
      rating: json['rating'],
      price: json['price'],
      phone: json['phone'],
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      alias: json['alias'],
      isClosed: json['is_closed'],
      reviewCount: json['review_count'],
      url: json['url'],
      imageUrl: json['image_url'],
    );
  }
```

The code works when a call is converted from the business/search endpoint, with the JSON printout being:

```
json = {rating: 4.5, price: $$, phone: +16316751500, id: D5dS2-8JXhZxo3BzMLV3xQ, name: Ichi sushi & ramen, alias: ichi-sushi-and-ramen, is_closed: false, review_count: 128, url: https://www.yelp.com/biz/ichi-sushi-and-ramen?adjust_creative=Aj73ii92JG9IDLNvRyn_Ow&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=Aj73ii92JG9IDLNvRyn_Ow, image_url: https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Phib_AwTkdD_kBV8r7179Q/o.jpg}
```

The Issue: I encounter the following exception

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
{id: D5dS2-8JXhZxo3BzMLV3xQ, alias: ichi-sushi-and-ramen...
 ^
```

when this response from business/details is called, saved and attempted to be converted to objects:

```
json = {id: D5dS2-8JXhZxo3BzMLV3xQ, alias: ichi-sushi-and-ramen, name: Ichi sushi & ramen, image_url: https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Phib_AwTkdD_kBV8r7179Q/o.jpg, is_claimed: true, is_closed: false, url: https://www.yelp.com/biz/ichi-sushi-and-ramen?adjust_creative=Aj73ii92JG9IDLNvRyn_Ow&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_lookup&utm_source=Aj73ii92JG9IDLNvRyn_Ow, phone: +15836751500, display_phone: (583) 675-1500, review_count: 128, categories: [{alias: sushi, title: Sushi Bars}, {alias: ramen, title: Ramen}], rating: 4.5, location: {address1: 200 Country Rd, address2: null, address3: , city: Bayshore, zip_code: 11803, country: US, state: NY, display_address: [200 Country Rd, Bayshore, NY 11803], cross_streets: }, coordinates: {latitude: 40.92842, longitude: -73.116}, photos: [https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/Phib_AwTkdD_kBV8r7179Q/o.jpg, https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bp<…> (*My note: debugger truncates with <...>*)
```

What is going wrong here? I have been trying many (and I mean many) different cases to rule out what the issue is but cannot find anything that is blatantly amiss. The only difference I can see is that the first type of call (business/search) starts with "rating" and contains fewer fields while the second type of call (business/details) returns much more data (note that I do not need much of it and hence do not need it in the Business object, but the nature of Yelp's api requires I do it in this way) and starts with the "id" field instead. Are these differences to blame and what does this error mean? Can you "plug in" a JSON to an object that has more fields than needed properties as I would like to keep the Business object as versatile as possible? Regardless, how could this be resolved? If more info is needed, please let me know. Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: I think the problem is that there aren't double quotations around the keys in your JSON, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650168/unexpected-character-on-decoding-json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further analyzing the code, @KhashayarMotarjemi's suggestion tipped me off on a possible problem: the way the data was encoded. To save the data, I ran the the JSON through the toString() method, stripping the data of all of its " " and making it unable to be correctly parsed as JSON later on when retrieved from memory. The correct method would be jsonEncode(yourData) as this converts it to a string to be saved, but preserves the format needed when decoded down the line. So to anyone reading, if you are trying to store your JSON as a string, you must use jsonEncode() and not toString() when doing so. I hope this can help someone in the future!